# Error database listener in spring boot aplication with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

How to write a listener that catches the moment when something happens to the database, e.g. a ResultSet exception that closes the entire embedded database. Is an `ApplicationListener` ok?
I'd like to close another task that runs at certain intervals when sth happens with database.

```java
public class DatabaseClosedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionEventListener` is the one you're looking for.

More details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionEventListener.html